# (Android) get rid of menu button without getting rid of action bar?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I want to get rid of the menu button that is on my action bar in my app, but still keep the action bar itself.  How do I go about doing this?  Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where your menu is created. See if you can modify or remove this to get your desired result.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```